# How to use Ampersand string using in Language translation in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.6

```
QString = "Command && Profile";
```

ru.ts file

```
<context>
<message>
        <source>Command &amp; Profile</source>
        <translation>Команда и профиль</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

Using translation this method will not working.. This scenario how to translate this.. Otherwise any other method is to do this translation.

Comment: I want to display Command & Profile.. So i used double ampersand.

Comment: I guess you have to write `&amp;&amp;` in .ts file.

Comment: Thanks zett.. Its Working.. thanks.. U r Guess is correct

Comment: Nice solution! It would be useful if you post it as an answer and mark it as accepted, so the rest of the community finds the answer quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `&amp;&amp;` in .ts file:

```xml
<context>
    <message>
        <source>Command &amp;&amp; Profile</source>
        <translation>Команда и профиль</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```